# warning: 'extern' ignored on this declaration

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, lex, lexer

I have in .l file `extern struct symbols;`
I try to use it in .y file as `%union {struct symbols symp;}` but when I try to run it , this message is appear `warning: 'extern' ignored on this declaration [-Wmissing-declarations] extern struct symbols;`

thank you

Comment: That error comes from your C compiler, not when you "try to run it". Please try to be more precise in your problem description. What were you compiling when you received that error?

Answer (score 0):

In C, a type does not have linkage. In other words, you cannot refer to members of a type whose definition is in a different translation unit unless you also declare them locally.

So it doesn't make sense to apply the `extern` modifier to a type declaration, since `extern` indicates that the definition is in a different translation unit. Hence the warning.

Note the difference between:

- `struct symbols;` – declares that `struct symbols` is a type (but does not define it)
- `struct symbols symp` - declares a variable or member of type `struct symbols`.

The second one is only possible if `struct symbols` has a definition in the same translation unit. But you could declare a *pointer* to an object of type `struct symbols` without a visible definition, as long as you don't attempt to refer to its members.